# Remove objects like table row before rendering

Tags: vb.net, itext, itext7

I am generating a document with itext7 in vb.net. The document is a payment reminder. The document contains 1 to many positions (I do not know how many positions the document will have at the end). Sometimes it could happen, that a position contains no amount. And I want to remove this position.

The reminder positions looks for example like this:

```
CustomerName   |      Amount |
---------------|-------------|
Jupiter Jones  |    1,100.12 |
Peter Crenshaw |        0.00 |
Bob Andrews    |      231.02 |
---------------|-------------|
Sum            |    1,331.14 |
```

The lines are added to the table with

```
table.AddCell(cell1)
table.AddCell(cell2)
```

This example is very simplified...sadly it is because of the data structure and the calculations that have to be made, that I do not know whether the position line has to be printed before starting the line (the first cell of the line) or not.

So is it possible to "remember" a kind of index or handle or anything else, so that I am able to remove certain objects from the itext7 document before I "send" it to the renderer?

The table should look like this after the "removement":

```
CustomerName   |      Amount |
---------------|-------------|
Jupiter Jones  |    1,100.12 |
Bob Andrews    |      231.02 |
---------------|-------------|
Sum            |    1,331.14 |
```

I hope you understand, what I mean...

To clarify some facts and answer the questions blow:

I wrote a wrapper-class (dll) for itext7 to create different types of pdfs with it. A whole table-creation contains of

```
obj.TableBegin({Cell1Width, Cell2Width})
while objMySqlDataReader.Read
    Dim calculatedAmount as Single = 0
    //do some calculations
    objCell1.Text = objMySqlDataReader("CustomerName")
    objCell2.Text = calculatedAmount
    obj.TableCreateRow({objCell1, objCell2})
End While
obj.TableEnd()
```

Method TableBegin

```
Private Sub TableBegin(ByVal ColWidths as Single())
    table = new Table(ColWidths)
    //some formattings and so on
End Sub
```

Method TableCreateRow

```
Private Sub TableCreateRow(byval arrCells as MyOwnCellType())
    For Each varCell As MyOwnCellType In arrCells
        Dim c As Cell = New Cell()
        Dim p As Paragraph = New Paragraph(varCell.Text)
        c.Add(p)
        //followed by some formatting lines like c.SetBackgroudColor
        //or c.SetBorder
        table.AddCell(c)
    Next
End Sub
```

Method TableEnd

```
Private Sub TableEnd()
    document.Add(table)
End Sub
```

The moment when I know whether a row as to be printed or not is variable. Sometimes I know it just after "printing" both cells of the row. But it could happen that I want to remove a table-row after the table has been "finished".

In another "document-type" a have a very similar problem, but there I need to remove a whole page of the document including Paragraphs, Tables, Images....

My utopian idea was, that I "save" the handle of each "possible to be removed object" in a list or array and after recognizing wheter the objects have to be printed or not I can either clear this array or remove all objects within this array by something like `document.remove(handle)`

Another utopian idea was, that I "collect" all "possible to be removed / printed objects" in any kind of array or list and after recognizing whether printing or not I can "push" these objects to the document or discard them.

It is difficult to discribe and even much more difficult to understand why I do not know "printing or not" **before** printing. But believe me - I do not know earlier. ;-)

Any idea or help is very appreciated.

Comment: Show how you create Cell1 and Cell2

Comment: *"that I do not know whether the position line has to be printed before starting the line (the first cell of the line) or not"* - but when *do* you know? At the end of that line? At the end of the table? At a completely unrelated time much later?

Comment: I added answers to your questions in text above...

Comment: I found out, that the "document" has a ```Protected Friend``` property called ```childElements``` which contains all elements within the doc. If it would be possible to access this ```childElements``` I could manipulate it and remove certain elements.  
Has anybody done something like this before? Is ```childElements``` accessible in any way?

Comment: Reflection should make that possible.

Comment: Thank you @mkl for this hint. I made it to get access to **read** the ```childElements``` property with this code:   

```Dim privateFieldValue As Object = tempDoc.GetType.BaseType.GetField("childElements", (BindingFlags.NonPublic Or BindingFlags.Instance)).GetValue(tempDoc)```  

But how can I get **writeable** access to the property?

Comment: By retrieving the `childElements` you get a `List<IElement>` of which you can call any methods, in particular also removal methods. Thus, you can already arbitrarily manipulate the list contents. But if you really want to exchange the list itself... where there is `GetValue`, there also is `SetValue`...

Comment: While all this is possible, though, I would propose you use a different approach: I would propose that you, in  your `TableBegin` method create a `List<Cell>` instance instead of a `Table`, in `TableCreateRow` add the newly created cells to that list instead of a table, and finally in `TableEnd` create a `Table`, add all the cells in your list to that table, and add the table to the document. This allows arbitrary manipulations before calling `TableEnd`. While having reflection as a tool where needed is great, one should try not to rely on reflection too much.

Comment: This is a possibility. But as said above, in another use case I have to remove many other elements like Images and Paragraphs. A whole page. Perhaps two pages (if the document-part is to long for a single page. The "element-remover" would be more flexible.

Comment: I tried to do it with this approach: ```Dim elements As List(Of IElement) = doc.GetType.BaseType.GetField("childElements", (BindingFlags.NonPublic Or BindingFlags.Instance)).GetValue(doc)``` 
        ```elements.RemoveAt(elements.Count - 1)```  
        ```doc.GetType.BaseType.GetField("childElements", (BindingFlags.NonPublic Or BindingFlags.Instance)).SetValue(doc, elements)```.  

The doc.childElements is correctly reduced by the last element, but this element is printed anyway... So removing the elemtn from childElements seems not to be enough. Any idea?

Comment: *"But as said above, in another use case I have to remove many other elements like Images and Paragraphs."* - then simply also collect such entities in your own lists. *"A whole page. Perhaps two pages (if the document-part is to long for a single page. The "element-remover" would be more flexible."* - no, it wouldn't. In particular ad your talking about content on multiple pages: as soon as you leave a page and start the next one, the content on the previous page is finalized on the page and then removing becomes difficult. In particular removing of parts of the previous page.

Comment: You should really consider collecting the elements to draw in your own structures **until you are sure they really are to be rendered** and the add them to the document. Manipulating internals of a library should be done only if strictly necessary, and in your case it is not necessary, not even really easier.

Comment: Ok. I will try to do this like you recommend it. Thank you for your help!